# 2010 iMac running Ubuntu 22.04.1 but unable to get graphics card Radeon HD 4670 to work

Tags: graphics, mac

So as the title says i've got an old 2010 iMac Intel i3 with a Radeon HD 4670. Originally had the issue where i couldnt get the screen to show and used nomodeset and radeon.modeset=0 in the grub to work around that unfortunately now whenever i try to watch video (mainly via plex) CPU usage is spiking straight to 100% and is unable to smoothly render the video.

When checking in settings i can see that the graphics are not listed as using the Radeon HD 4670 (the graphics are listed as "llvm pipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 128 bits)") and im thinking that's why the issue maybe occuring as plex and other video can run perfectly fine on Mac OS when utilising the GPU.

Bit of a noob with this stuff so please go easy on me  Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Adjusted Ubuntu verision to the correct version (22.04.1)

EDIT2: Output of `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for p: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV730/M96-XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0420000-d042ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0400000-d041ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

EDIT3: Output of `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` & `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'` :

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96-XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670] [1002:9488]
```

```
sudo dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    2.488817] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    2.490559] [drm] amdgpu version: 5.16.9.22.20
[    2.492284] [drm] OS DRM version: 5.15.0
[   10.592084] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
```

EDIT4: Output of `lsmod | egrep 'radeon|amdgpu '` & `dmesg | grep -i iommu`:

```
lsmod | egrep 'radeon|amdgpu '
amdgpu              10461184  0
```

&

```
 sudo dmesg | grep -i iommu
[    0.349557] pci 0000:00:00.0: DMAR: BIOS has allocated no shadow GTT; disabling IOMMU for graphics
[    0.359162] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.359162] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode
[    2.346456] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system - This is not a bug.
```

EDIT5: I've been advised to add that this issue persists in X.org

EDIT6: /var/log/Xorg.0.log file output (less the list of chipsets):

```
[    53.684] Current Operating System: Linux Linux-iMac 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64
[    53.684] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=d67c8579-ed65-48e8-8446-03bbb27b92d0 ro
[    53.684] xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    53.684] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    53.684]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    53.684] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    53.685] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov  5 08:22:41 2022
[    53.748] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    54.237] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    54.237] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    54.237] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    54.237] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    54.281] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    54.281] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    54.281] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    54.281] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    54.281] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    54.281] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    54.476] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    54.476]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    54.476] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    54.476]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    54.476] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    54.476]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    54.477] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    54.477]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    54.477] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    54.477]    Entry deleted from font path.
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[    54.477] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    54.477] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    54.477] (II) Loader magic: 0x564ba8289020
[    54.477] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    54.477]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    54.477]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[    54.477]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[    54.477]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    54.478] (++) using VT number 2

[    54.480] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    54.489] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 1002:9488:106b:00b6 rev 0, Mem @ 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0420000/65536, I/O @ 0x00002000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    54.493] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    54.715] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    56.328] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    56.328]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    56.328]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    56.328] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[    56.328] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    56.328] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    56.328] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    56.328] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    56.328] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    56.386] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    56.505] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    56.505]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0
[    56.505]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    56.505]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    56.575] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    56.576] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    56.833] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    56.833]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0
[    56.833]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    56.833]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    56.833] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    56.833] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    57.013] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.013]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.21.1
[    57.013]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    57.013]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    57.013] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    57.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    57.288] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.288]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[    57.288]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    57.288]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    57.288] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    57.289] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    57.452] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.452]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[    57.452]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    57.452]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    57.452] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon chipsets:
[    57.472] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    57.472] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    57.472] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    57.473] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    57.473] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    57.473] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    57.473] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    57.473] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    57.473] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.474] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    57.519] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.519]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    57.519]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    57.520] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    57.520] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    57.520] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    57.520] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    57.521] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.521]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    57.521]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    57.521] (II) FBDEV(3): using default device
[    57.521] vesa: Refusing to run on UEFI
[    57.521] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    57.521] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    57.522] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    57.522] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    57.522] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    57.522] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    57.522] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.522] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    57.522] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    57.522] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    57.522] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    57.523] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    57.523] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 8100kB)
[    57.523] (DB) xf86MergeOutputClassOptions unsupported bus type 0
[    57.523] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    57.523] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    57.523] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 1920)
[    57.523] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 207.4 MHz, 85.3 kHz, 77.2 Hz
[    57.523] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0  207.38  1920 1952 2192 2432  1080 1084 1088 1104 -hsync -vsync -csync (85.3 kHz b)
[    57.523] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    57.523] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    57.523] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    57.524] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[    57.524] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    57.524] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    57.524] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    57.524] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    57.527] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.527]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    57.527]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    57.527] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    57.573] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    57.597] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    57.597] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    57.598] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    57.598] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    57.599] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    57.600] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    57.600] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    57.600] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    57.601] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    57.601] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    57.602] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    57.602] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    57.602] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    57.603] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    57.603] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    57.604] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    57.604] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    57.605] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    57.605] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    57.605] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    57.606] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    57.606] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    57.606] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    57.607] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    57.607] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    57.607] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[    57.607] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    57.607] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    57.608] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    69.154] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    69.154] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    69.154] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    69.154] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    69.155] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    69.155] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    70.832] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    70.832] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    70.832] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    70.832] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    71.205] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    71.205]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[    71.205]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    71.205]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    71.205] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    71.207] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 24 paused 0
[    71.207] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    71.207] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    71.421] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.422] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    71.422] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    71.422] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    71.422] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.422] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.466] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.466] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    71.467] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[    71.467] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.467] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    71.468] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 27 paused 0
[    71.468] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    71.468] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    71.471] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.471] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    71.471] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[    71.472] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3/event3"
[    71.472] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    71.472] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.472] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.475] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.475] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    71.477] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    71.477] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.477] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    71.478] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 28 paused 0
[    71.478] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    71.478] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    71.480] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.480] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    71.481] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[    71.481] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    71.481] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    71.481] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.481] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.483] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.484] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    71.485] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    71.485] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.485] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    71.487] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 29 paused 0
[    71.487] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    71.487] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    71.489] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.489] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    71.489] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    71.490] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[    71.490] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    71.490] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.490] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.492] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.492] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    71.494] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
[    71.494] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.494] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.497] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX (/dev/input/event5)
[    71.497] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.497] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DaKai 2.4G RX'
[    71.499] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 30 paused 0
[    71.499] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX: always reports core events
[    71.499] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    71.504] (II) event5  - DaKai 2.4G RX: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.505] (II) event5  - DaKai 2.4G RX: device is a keyboard
[    71.505] (II) event5  - DaKai 2.4G RX: device removed
[    71.505] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:0E8F:00A8.0002/input/input4/event5"
[    71.506] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DaKai 2.4G RX" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    71.506] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.506] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.512] (II) event5  - DaKai 2.4G RX: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.512] (II) event5  - DaKai 2.4G RX: device is a keyboard
[    71.515] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse (/dev/input/event6)
[    71.515] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    71.515] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse'
[    71.517] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 31 paused 0
[    71.517] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: always reports core events
[    71.517] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    71.520] (II) event6  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    71.520] (II) event6  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: device is a pointer
[    71.520] (II) event6  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: device removed
[    71.521] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0003/input/input6/event6"
[    71.521] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    71.521] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    71.521] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    71.521] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    71.521] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    71.523] (II) event6  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    71.523] (II) event6  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: device is a pointer
[    71.524] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    71.524] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.524] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.526] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX System Control (/dev/input/event7)
[    71.526] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.526] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DaKai 2.4G RX System Control'
[    71.527] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 32 paused 0
[    71.527] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: always reports core events
[    71.527] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    71.530] (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.530] (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: device is a keyboard
[    71.530] (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: device removed
[    71.530] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0003/input/input7/event7"
[    71.530] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DaKai 2.4G RX System Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    71.530] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.530] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.534] (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.534] (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: device is a keyboard
[    71.536] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control (/dev/input/event8)
[    71.536] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.536] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control'
[    71.537] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72 fd 33 paused 0
[    71.537] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: always reports core events
[    71.537] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    71.539] (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.539] (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[    71.539] (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: device removed
[    71.539] (II) libinput: DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: needs a virtual subdevice
[    71.539] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0003/input/input8/event8"
[    71.539] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    71.539] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    71.539] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    71.540] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    71.540] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    71.541] (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.542] (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[    71.543] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DaKai 2.4G RX (/dev/input/event9)
[    71.543] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.543] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.544] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line (/dev/input/event13)
[    71.544] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.544] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.544] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Headphone (/dev/input/event14)
[    71.544] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.544] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.545] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID SPDIF In (/dev/input/event15)
[    71.545] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    71.545] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    71.546] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh (/dev/input/event10)

[    71.546] (**) Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.546] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh'
[    71.547] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event10 13:74 fd 34 paused 0
[    71.547] (**) Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: always reports core events
[    71.547] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[    71.549] (II) event10 - Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.550] (II) event10 - Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: device is a keyboard
[    71.550] (II) event10 - Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: device removed
[    71.550] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input16/event10"
[    71.550] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    71.550] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.550] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.552] (II) event10 - Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.552] (II) event10 - Built-in iSight: Built-in iSigh: device is a keyboard
[    71.553] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver (/dev/input/event11)
[    71.553] (**) Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.553] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver'
[    71.554] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event11 13:75 fd 35 paused 0
[    71.554] (**) Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: always reports core events
[    71.554] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[    71.556] (II) event11 - Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.557] (II) event11 - Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    71.557] (II) event11 - Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: device removed
[    71.557] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:05AC:8242.0001/input/input11/event11"
[    71.557] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
[    71.557] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.557] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    71.559] (II) event11 - Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    71.559] (II) event11 - Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    71.570] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    71.570] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control'
[    71.570] (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72
[    71.570] (**) DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: always reports core events
[    71.570] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    71.570] (II) libinput: DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
[    71.570] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0E8F:00A8.0003/input/input8/event8"
[    71.570] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[    71.570] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    71.570] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140253/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-temple-2010-imac-running-ubuntu-22-04-1-but-un).

Comment: @PatrickTemple Please see the new comments in the chat link above

Comment: Hey @Av4k100 did you find a solution? I have the same iMac (Mid 2010 | ATI Radeon HD 4670 | https://support.apple.com/kb/sp588 ) and the same problem: I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed, but I get a black screen without nomodeset. Videos (for example Youtube) are laggy and gnome-shell is using a lot of cpu (often 100% just by moving the cursor). And idk if it helps but I noticed that the grub menu never shows even when nomodeset is on and GRUB_TIMEOUT is set to 30 seconds for example.